# Hatcher Example 2.39

Tags: algebraic-topology, solution-verification

In Hatcher example 2.39, they compute the cellular homology of $T^3=S^1\times S^1\times S^1$. In that example, it states that $T^3$ can be obtained by a cube by identifying each pair of opposite square faces as the first of the below figure
[image: .]
why is this the case? Why $S^1\times S^1\times S^1$ is homeomorphic to the first figure?

Comment: Do you know how to make $S^1$ from a line segment, and $S^1\times S^1$ from a square? This is the natural generalisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I = [0,1]$. You certainly know that $S^1$ is the quotient space of $I$ obtained by identifying the endpoints $0,1$ of $I$. A quotient map is given by
$$p : I \to S^1, p(x) = (\cos x, \sin x).$$
Now define
$$P : I^3 \to T^3 = S^1 \times S^1 \times S^1, P(x,y,z) = (p(x),p(y),p(z)) .$$
This is a surjective map from a compact space to a Hausdorff space, hence a continuous closed surjection and thus a quotient map.

Now $P(x,y,z) = P(x',y',z')$ with $(x,y,z) \ne (x',y',z')$ means that at least one the following three conditions is satisfied:

1. $\{x,x'\} = \{0,1\}$
2. $\{y,y'\} = \{0,1\}$
3. $\{z,z'\} = \{0,1\}$

These describe the fact that each pair of opposite square faces is identified as in the first of your figures.